# bitbucket commits on master branch cannot be found

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Recently, we've had to use bitbucket for a new project, so I'm not familiar with its interface. 
A strange thing we've come across is that the latest commit in master branch seems to be 3 months ago when under the commits section of bitbucket and after selecting the "All branches" option I can see commits made on master.
These commits, however, cannot be found when I search on master branch.
Any explanation about this?

Comment: Is this a publicly available repo? If yes, which?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have made the commits and have not pushed it to origin? and you might be looking at the origin branch and not finding the commits.
just one possible problem.